# Troubleshooting an Adobe InDesign CS6 installation

Tags: installation, adobe-indesign

When I try to install Adobe InDesign CS6 I got the following error message:

> Windows cannot find:
>   'c:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Local\Adobe\OOBE\PDApp\core..\D6..\DECore\Setup.e...
>
> Make sure you typed the name correctly and then try again.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what it is that you're asking, even after my edit.  Are you looking for us to debug that issue, or help you find the file?  or are you asking questions on how to install Adobe InDesign?  I suggest that you try to elaborate on the problem, steps that you've taken, and what the eventual outcome that you're hoping to get here.

Comment: First I tried to install the application , the installation start normal after 15% it's crashed and stopped from a problem in the DVD or from the copy that I installing ,I replace the copy and get new copy and this copy fine ,but when i trying to install the new copy a message above appear , i think there are still old files exist from the crashed one and it's damage the installation process , so maybe I have to clear everything that related to the old crashed installation ,maybe registry from cmd i don't know how to use these stuff.
I would be thankful if you can help me,And also if you not.

Comment: You're not... by chance... installing a pirated copy?  Because this sounds like issues with the installer not being completely correct (a common pirated software issue).